# Relation on set A to the power of two, three, four etc

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Im a bit stuck on understanding the following situation:

Consider the relation:

```
R = {(0, 2),(0, 3),(1, 0),(1, 3),(2, 0),(2, 3)}
```

On the set A.

```
A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Then to define R to the power 2, 3 and four, I thought it could be solved by defining the power to the amount of "steps" that can be taken. For example from 0 i can go to 2 and back to 0, so (0,0) can be added to the new relation. In this way I am able to answer it:

```
R to the power of 2 = {(0, 0),(0, 3),(1, 2),(1, 3),(2, 2),(2, 3)},
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way of solving it (probably not) and during my search for answers I only find information on powersets.

Any background information would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: The term you need to look for here is composition of relations (you are composing $R$ with itself).

Comment: Your answer for $R^2$ is correct!

Comment: That is exactly the right interpretation and at a cursory glance you seem to have it correct.  For relations $R$ and $S$ one has $R\circ S = \{(x,z)~:~\exists y~\text{such that}~(x,y)\in R~\text{and}~(y,z)\in S\}$ and $R^2 = R\circ R$.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments, is there any "kindergarden" way to solve this? By for example draw nodes for each point and connect them?

Comment: Yes, you can draw the relation as an oriented graph, and the elements that are related in the $n$'th power of the relation are then those where you can go from one to the other via a path of length exactly $n$.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasKildetoft so that is basically what I did. Draw it as an oriented graph and the amount of "steps" that can be made are depending on the power, so in the power of 2, 2 steps can be made, and in the power of 3, 3 steps can be made etc.

Comment: Yes, precisely (though remember that you need the exact number of steps, but that whenever you have an element of the form $(a,a)$ in the relation, you get a loop that you can use as many times as you want).

Comment: By the way, a note of caution: For larger powers, this is probably not a very good way to do things, since it becomes hard to see if you have gone through all paths of a given length. Instead, you can do a similar process with two different relations by "coloring" the arrows in the graph and taking steps that are first one color then the other (in the given order). For computing $R^n$ you can then instead calculate $R^{n-1}\circ R$ using this.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks again, if you still got any useful source you could share with me I would appreciate it!